# A Smart Girl -*_*-

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

A little girl staying next door just came from school. I asked her, "Hey, Akari. Come here." She came running. She was holding a book in her hand. Opening it she started scribbling something. Once she was done, I gave her a chocolate with a smile.

I didn't know what she scribbled. I came back home and remembered the lines -

> *Even Ends*
>   *Wide at Mid*
>   *My Rhyme*

I was not sure what it was until I went back and asked the girl about it. I imagined *"Smart Girl!"*

Well, do you know what she scribbled?

**Some notes-**

1. No, it's not lateral thinking.
2. Yes, it will require a little knowledge.
3. Quoted text is enough to find the answer though the story might give a clue. But do not spend time finding the clue in the story. Nothing much there.
4. Fonts do not matter.
5. Ignore grammatical errors if any. The stuff used might help a bit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

She wrote a

> [haiku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku)

It has **even ends**

> 5 syllables for 1st and 3rd line

It is **wide at mid**

> 7 syllables for the 2nd line

And it **my rhyme**

> never rhymes

Also

> name Akari sounds like a Japanese one, so it is a clue to haiku.

And there is another clue

> the number of unique letters in the 3 lines is 5-7-5 respectively, which is the numbers of syllables in haiku

**OP's edit -**

> The three lines speak about Haiku's pattern which is **5-7-5**
>  ***Even Ends*** - uses 5 unique characters **e,v,n,d,s**
>  ***Wide at Mid*** - uses 7 unique characters **w,i,d,e,a,t,m**
>  ***My Rhyme*** - uses 5 unique characters **m,y,r,h,e**

Comment: faaaast hahah same here, after reading the name and the lines thought the same as your solution. aaaah the syllables match adding the "it has", "it is" and "and it" :OO

Comment: Hah! Too quick. +25 :D Hope you liked it! Thanks

Comment: From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akari) "Akari is a **Japanese** given name and term meaning "light" or "glimmer"."

Comment: How does "my rhyme" mean "doesn't rhyme"?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I thought it only means to refer to rhyming - not rhyming at all is also rhyme-related.

Comment: @oleslaw - You can update your answer. Check the number of unique letters in all the three lines. I thought you already updated that in your answer :D

Comment: @oleslaw- I have added a little more if you don't mind! :)